# Tutorial for publishing and consuming toolbox using ArcGIS Server 10.1

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there a simple tutorial for publishing and consuming toolbox using ArcGIS Server 10.1.

In 10 I can just right click and publish my tools but in 10.1, things seems to change a lot.

May I know if there is any simple tutorial from start to end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any tutorials that walk thru this process step-by-step.
ESRI's documentation is nowhere near the level that is actually needed to get something working...BUT, it's better than nothing.

Here's an intro to publishing Geoprocessing services:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_publishing_a_geoprocessing_service/0154000004sz000000/

Here is a link to the section on how to consume the services in a web app:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_geoprocessing_tasks_in_web_applications/0154000004v8000000/

Good luck.